# Is there way to add Language shortcuts in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, text-editing

On iOS, I could add a language short cut easily in settings. Like `gd` stands for "have a good day". Is there a way of doing that on a Mac?

I don't know if this is even possible since OS X doesn't have an ubiquitous spelling check, as it may seem. I hope I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in

```
System Preferences > Language and Text > "Text" Tab
> [√] Use symbol and text substitution
```

Then hit the [+] button at the bottom of the list and add your shortcut text and your substitution text.

[image]

I believe this feature first became available in Snow Leopard (Mac OS X v10.6.x).

If the built-in feature runs out of steam for you, there's always been a wealth of third party "text expander" and macro utilities for the Mac. Here's a [nice rundown](http://www.macworld.com/article/151287/2010/05/textexpansionutilities.html).